# How can I run emacs in gnome terminal without popup interface?

Tags: command-line, emacs

Just like using emacs on putty. I just transfered to Ubuntu from windows.

Answer (score 38):

To run emacs in the Terminal without a GUI (i.e., without it creating a graphical window for itself), use:

`emacs -nw`

The `-nw` flag stands for "no window."

Answer (score 9):

The command-line emacs is installed along with the GUI.
To run it, use the -nw option. An explanation from man emacs:

```
-nw, --no-window-system
Tell Emacs not to use its special interface to X. If you use
this switch when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window, display
is done in that window.
```

So run the following command to use emacs from the command-line:

```
emacs -nw
```

If you don't want to have to type `emacs -nw`, you could create an alias. Put the following line in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias emacs="emacs -nw"
```

You can add this alias in one line by using I/O Redirection:

```
echo alias emacs="emacs -nw" >> ~/.bashrc
```